# Automatically smash all inline math

Tags: math-mode, macros, spacing, math-operators, inline

Is there some trick to automatically apply the `\smash` command to all inline math? I've found questions about the `\smash` command, but nobody is asking how to get the `\smash` effect both vertically and horizontally. With "horizontally" I mean, for instance, that expressions with binary operators such as $1+1$ should always have the standard spacing, the two symbols "1" should not get closer to or farther from "+".

It's important, though, that this in no way affects display math. It would be nice to also have some way to occasionally use the the standard `$...$` command without `\smash`, but this is just a secondary request.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
 \textbf{Standard output:}

 When we deal with a field of characteristic $2$, we have the property $1+1=0$.

 \textbf{Desired output:}

 When we deal with a field of characteristic $2$, we have the property $\smash{1+1=0}$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: the `\smash` in your example is unrelated to the horizonat space difference, you would see the same with simply `we have the property ${1+1=0}$.`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Of course `\smash` is ***not*** meant for this. Forget it.

If you really want that the space around binary operation symbols is not affected by justification adjustments, simply do

```
\medmuskip=1\medmuskip
```

in the document preamble, which will remove stretchability and shrinkability. You might also want to do

```
\thickmuskip=1\thickmuskip
```

But after a while, you'll realize that the quality of your documents will be drastically reduced instead of improved.

If you want to preserve the spacing in an occasional formula, just put it between braces.

Comment: +1: Maybe I am not seeing the obvious but isn't `\medmuskip=1\medmuskip` the same as `\medmuskip=\medmuskip` ("1" removed).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner no it removes the stretch and shrink components, try `\showthe\medmuskip` before and after.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see, thanks for the explanation.